# Troubles with mic preamp for headphones with integrated microphone

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain, microphone, preamp, biasing

I am designing a preamp intended to interface with a microphone in common headphones (e.g. apple earpods, or sony headphones with a microphone) which will then connect to my ADC's inputs.

I've developed a circuit based on a reference design, however the reference does not take into account the need to bias the microphone. From what I gather, I need to provide ~1.65V to the mic.

My circuit is using an AC voltage source @ 4mVrms to simulate output from the microphone (not sure if that's a fair model) and I'm not including any mic resistance.

My questions:

- How would I bias this mic? providing power to net 8 does not show a bias (in simulation).
- How do I ensure the gain of this pre-amp is correct? Finding datasheets for the mic in apple earpods is next to impossible so I don't have any real specs to go from.
- Are there any reference designs that perform the same task?

[image]

Comment: [A TI design for an electret microphone preamplifier.](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/tidu765)

Comment: That includes biasing for the microphone.

Comment: @JRE I saw that reference as well, however I can't be certain the gain is correct for these types of microphones. Do you know of any other with this specific application?

Comment: Then look at how TI provides the bias, and apply that to your circuit.

Comment: It shows R1 = (Vcc - Vmic)/Is. I don't know Is (no datasheet for these mics) which makes getting that resistor value difficult.

Comment: Find a data sheet.

Comment: [Check the assumptions that the Android specifications make about the microphone.](https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/headset/plug-headset-spec)  The current draw of the microphones isn't fixed  - Android headsets have to work with whatever microphone you plug in.  The specification assumes certain things, and it pretty much just works.  This isn't rocket science - you don't even need "close" for it to work, just "in the ball park" and it'll go.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @JRE. If I'm interpreting this correctly, I'll simply supply 2.2V over a 2.2k resistor to bias the mic as it shows in the android docs. is that really the only change I'd need?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to the microphone bias problem is to use a a resistor to provide current to the electret microphone.

It usually looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg30AW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The correct value for R1 would normally depend somewhat on the microphone.

Since you are going to be plugging just any old microphone in a cellphone headset into it, you can't really do any kind of calculations to make it work better.

The [Android headset specifications](https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/headset/plug-headset-spec) show a 2.2k ohm resistor to provide bias to the headset microphone.

That's when using a 2.2V source.  You could reduce the voltage to your microphone to 2.2V, or just do what everyone one else does:  just ignore the voltage and use 2.2k regardless.

---

If you were doing something with low noise and microphones purpose bought with datasheets, you would probably want to go with something like this [Texas Instruments verified design note.](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/tidu765)

That walks you through properly designing a low noise transimpedance microphone preamplifier.  It does require that you have the specifications of the microphone and the desired output level for a specific input level.

Comment: Thanks again for your help @JRE. Moving forward with this approach.